# generate random numbers in c ++ for small intervals

Tags: c++

I'm working on a program to calculate the odds of a poker game, it's in process. I found how to generate random numbers but these random numbers depend on time and are not appropriate for generating random numbers in a small interval. I would like to know how I can generate random numbers without having to depend on computer time.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>  

using namespace std;

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int N = 1000, T=100;
    int j;
    float tcouple = 0, ttrio = 0, tfull = 0, tpoker = 0, trien = 0;
    struct Lettre{ int numero; char baton;};
    Lettre lettre[5];
    for(int a = 0; a < T; a++)
    {
        int couple = 0, trio = 0, full = 0, poker = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i< N; i++){
            int d = 0 ;
            for(j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                int r = 0;
                lettre[j].numero = (1 + rand() % 13);
                r = (1 + rand() % 4);
                switch(r)
                {
                    case 1:
                        lettre[j].baton = 'T';
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        lettre[j].baton = 'P';
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        lettre[j].baton = 'C';
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        lettre[j].baton = 'D';
                        break;
                }
            }
            for(int l = 0; l < 4; l++)
            {
                for(int k = l + 1; k<5; k++)
                {
                    if(lettre[l].numero == lettre[k].numero)
                        d = d + 1;
                }
            }
            if (d == 1)
                couple = couple + 1;
            if (d == 3)
                trio = trio + 1;
            if(d == 4)
                full = full + 1;
            if(d==6)
                poker = poker + 1;
        }
        tcouple = tcouple + couple;
        ttrio = ttrio + trio;
        tfull = tfull + full;
        tpoker = tpoker + poker;
    }
    trien=(T*N)-(tcouple+ttrio+tfull+tpoker);
    cout << "probabilite couple: " << tcouple/(T*N) <<endl;
    cout << "probabilite trio: " << ttrio/(T*N) <<endl;
    cout << "probabilite full: " << tfull/(T*N) <<endl;
    cout << "probabilite poker: " << tpoker/(T*N) <<endl;
    cout << "probabilite rien: " << trien/(T*N) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [`uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to keep a random numbers pool, which is filled at start or once a time period. It should be big enough so every time you get new random value from it it was a new one. In this case you may use `uniform_int_distribution` as Timo suggested or even `rand`.

```
struct RandPool
{
    void Generate()
    {
        srand(time(nullptr));
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000'000; ++i)
            mNumbers.push_back(rand());
        mIndex = 0;
    }

    int Next() 
    {
        return mNumbers[mIndex++];
    }

private:

    int mIndex = 0;
    std::vector<int> mNumbers;
};
```